# Sort the text span on list in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I need to sort the text in alphabetical order.

Here is my result for sorting by alphabetical, But with each click on `Click to sort` to sort the results produces different.

What is not done correctly?

What do I need to change in the code?

Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    var $sort = this;
    var $list = $('#sort-list');
    var $listLi = $('.sort', $list);
    $listLi.sort(function(a, b) {
      var keyA = $(a).find('.item').text();
      var keyB = $(b).find('.item').text();
      if ($($sort).hasClass('asc')) {
        return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
      }
    });
    $.each($listLi, function(index, row) {
      $list.append(row);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link-sort-list asc"><i class="icon-asc"></i>Click to sort</a>


<ul id="sort-list" class="list-group">
  <li class="labeled_count list-group-item justify-content-between label_list"> 
    <span class="count_result badge badge-default badge-pill">items: 000</span> 
  </li>
 
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Chandrasekar Balasubramaniyam</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Charles Bendernagel</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Ayazur Rehman</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Devkala Magar</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Dmitri Sazonoff</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Coco Li</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Dimpu Buddha</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Dzianis Shvets</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Heng Ji</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Huran Ibrahim</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Harshil Shah</span>
  </li>
  
  
 
 
  
</ul>
```

Comment: *But with each click on Click to sort to sort the results produces different.* It is not happening on chrome, which browser are you testing with?

Comment: I'm testing the chrome and the answer helped, it turned out.

Comment: Yes, I was able to replicate your error as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `localCompare` instead of comparison using `<`

```
    return keyA.localeCompare( keyB );
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    var $sort = this;
    var $list = $('#sort-list');
    var $listLi = $('.sort', $list);
    $listLi.sort(function(a, b) {
      var keyA = $(a).find('.item').text();
      var keyB = $(b).find('.item').text();
      if ($($sort).hasClass('asc')) {
        return keyA.localeCompare( keyB );
      }
    });
    $.each($listLi, function(index, row) {
      $list.append(row);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link-sort-list asc"><i class="icon-asc"></i>Click to sort</a>


<ul id="sort-list" class="list-group">
  <li class="labeled_count list-group-item justify-content-between label_list"> 
    <span class="count_result badge badge-default badge-pill">items: 000</span> 
  </li>
 
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Chandrasekar Balasubramaniyam</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Charles Bendernagel</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Ayazur Rehman</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Devkala Magar</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Dmitri Sazonoff</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Coco Li</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Dimpu Buddha</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Dzianis Shvets</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Heng Ji</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Huran Ibrahim</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Harshil Shah</span>
  </li>
  
  
 
 
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

return (keyA < keyB) ? -1 : (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Code example:

```js
$('a').click(function (e) {
  var $list = $('#sort-list');
  var $listLi = $('#sort-list .sort');
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $listLi.sort(function (a, b) {
    var keyA = $(a).find('.item').text();
    var keyB = $(b).find('.item').text();
    return keyA.localeCompare(keyB);
  });
  $list.append($listLi);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="link-sort-list asc"><i class="icon-asc"></i>Click to sort</a>


<ul id="sort-list" class="list-group">
  <li class="labeled_count list-group-item justify-content-between label_list"> 
    <span class="count_result badge badge-default badge-pill">items: 000</span> 
  </li>
 
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Chandrasekar Balasubramaniyam</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Charles Bendernagel</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Ayazur Rehman</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Devkala Magar</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Dmitri Sazonoff</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Coco Li</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Dimpu Buddha</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Dzianis Shvets</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Heng Ji</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Huran Ibrahim</span>
  </li>
  <li class="sort list-group-item justify-content-between label_list">
    <span class="item">Harshil Shah</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```